# Moving the robot tears costmap apart

Tags: ros-melodic, ros-kinetic, costmap-2d-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I use [cartographer](http://wiki.ros.org/cartographer) as SLAM to generate a map based on laser information. To perform automated exploration, I need to extract information from the generated map. I use the transform node in cartographer to get the  [nav_msgs::OccupancyGrid](http://docs.ros.org/melodic/api/nav_msgs/html/msg/OccupancyGrid.html).

In my exploration node, I have a [costmap_2d::Costmap2DROS](http://wiki.ros.org/costmap_2d) object to hold the map information. The parameter file is here:

```yaml
global_costmap:
  global_frame: "map"
  robot_base_frame: "base_link"
  transform_tolerance: 0.2
  update_frequency: 5
  publish_frequency: 1
  rolling_window: false
  always_send_full_costmap: false

  plugins:
    - {name: cartographer_layer, type: "costmap_2d::StaticLayer"}
    # - {name: obstacles, type: "costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer"}
    # - {name: inflation, type: "costmap_2d::InflationLayer"}

  cartographer_layer:
    map_topic: "/map"
    first_map_only: false
    # there is no /map_updates topic from cartographer
    subscribe_to_updates: false
    track_unknown_space: true
    use_maximum: false
    unknown_cost_value: -1
    trinary_costmap: true
```

The map looks good in the beginning: (this is only the costmap without the cartographer map)
[image: Gazebo image]
[image: Generated map]

But as soon as the robot starts rotating/moving, the map looks like this: (The good map in the background is the "/map" topic from cartographer)
[image: Generated map after moving]

I thought this might be a tf issue. But I'm not sure.
The Map is published in the correct frame and my tf tree looks fine too.
[image: Tf frames in rviz]
[image: Tf tree]

I've used a raw costmap2d before and used this code to update my map. There everything worked as intended.

```cpp
void IndoorExplorer::updateFullMap(const nav_msgs::OccupancyGrid::ConstPtr& msg)
{    
  unsigned int size_in_cells_x = msg->info.width;
  unsigned int size_in_cells_y = msg->info.height;
  double resolution            = msg->info.resolution;
  double origin_x              = msg->info.origin.position.x;
  double origin_y              = msg->info.origin.position.y;

  debug_msg("Received full new map, resizing to:", size_in_cells_x, ", ", size_in_cells_y);
  costmap->resizeMap(size_in_cells_x, size_in_cells_y, resolution, origin_x, origin_y);

  // lock as we are accessing raw underlying map
  auto* mutex = costmap->getMutex();
  std::lock_guard<costmap_2d::Costmap2D::mutex_t> lock(*mutex);

  // fill map with data
  unsigned char* costmap_data = costmap->getCharMap();
  size_t costmap_size         = costmap->getSizeInCellsX() * costmap->getSizeInCellsY();
  debug_msg("Full map update,", costmap_size, "values");
  for (size_t i = 0; i < costmap_size && i < msg->data.size(); ++i)
  {
    unsigned char cell_cost = static_cast<unsigned char>(msg->data[i]);
    costmap_data[i]         = cost_translation_table__[cell_cost];
  }
  debug_msg("Map updated, written", costmap_size, "values");
}
```

So what is wrong with the [update function of Costmap2DROS](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/costmap_2d/html/costmap__2d__ros_8cpp_source.html#l00417)?

I'm currently hacking my way through the code, but I've no clue whats going on there.

**Edit:** This is the last time, I'll edit this post, because it looks like there are no incrementel updates. Everytime I click edit, I loos everything that was not in my original post. This is the worst.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/351261/moving-the-robot-tears-costmap-apart/) by [Darkproduct](https://answers.ros.org/users/52476/darkproduct/) on ROS Answers with karma: 100 on 2020-05-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [artemiialessandrini](https://answers.ros.org/users/36583/artemiialessandrini/) on 2020-05-03**:
Maybe this [bug](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/issues/959)?

Try to roll back to previous commits

Or fetch latest commits, seems like it's fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I believe what you're seeing is this: https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/issues/959

Resolved in https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/pull/972. There has been releases since then (https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/releases) so I think it just needs to be synced to apt. In the mean-time, build from source.

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2020-05-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Darkproduct](https://answers.ros.org/users/52476/darkproduct/) on 2020-05-04**:
I'm not sure if that's the issue, because I've installed the kinetic version of the costmap2d package. `ros-kinetic-costmap-2d/now 1.14.5-1xenial-20191214-114303+0000 amd64`

I believe I use [this function](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/costmap_2d/html/static__layer_8cpp_source.html#l00164).

**Comment by [Darkproduct](https://answers.ros.org/users/52476/darkproduct/) on 2020-05-04**:
Maybe you are right. I've read [issue #792](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/pull/792) where the problem starts, and that is in kinetic. I'll lock more into this.

**Comment by [Darkproduct](https://answers.ros.org/users/52476/darkproduct/) on 2020-05-04**:
I confirmed that the map can be updated, but not resized, by moving obstacles in the FOV, which works fine.

**Comment by [Darkproduct](https://answers.ros.org/users/52476/darkproduct/) on 2020-05-05**:
This solved my problem. I had version 1.14.5 installed and updated it to 1.14.7. Now everything looks fine.